# C , linebreak without linefeed?

Tags: c, printf, stdout, linefeed

Silly question but,
   Is it possible to break a line on stdout without the line feed using printf();? If not, any tips on how I would overwrite 2+ lines, if possible?

I'm trying to generate sort of a progress bar but on multiple lines.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
So yeah I accepted the below answer although it won't work for my specific case.
I'm trying to overwrite 2+lines
rather than a single line.

```
printf("12345\r");
fflush(stdout);
printf("67890\n");
```

The result of which is 
$ ./a.out 
67890

But what I'm trying to achieve is have 2+ lines be overwritten with new data.
Similar to a progress bar but on 2+ lines except I have a percentage number for some data.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the linefeed?  What OS are you running?

Comment: Linux, Ubuntu , but this should work on any flavor really. Well the reason I don't want to use linefeed is because I thought using linefeed i can't go back using to the beginning of the "line" using /r. I have a print "---->/r"; and the bar grows through iterations. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to break the line "without the line feed".  That is what the newline character is for...

Comment: Right, but say I break the line with '\n', then that line is fixed. How would I overwrite it?

Comment: To add on to it: How would you overwrite 
   
   `printf ("something\n"something\n");`

As opposed to `printf("something\rnothing    \n");`

Comment: @janjust: "any flavor"? What about the OSes that don't have terminals?

Comment: This software is for terminal use only.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.  Unfortunately it doesn't quite work like that.  Usually, although it is a bit of a hack, re-writing a line in the terminal is done using a carefully calculated number of backspace (`\b`) characters to erase the previous characters.

Comment: aah! Yeah that will work, The line is usually fixed.
Much Appreciated.

Comment: I'll add an answer...

Comment: There is no portable way to achieve this in C; Your question is a terminal question, rather than a C question, and unfortunately there aren't such standards for terminals (AFAIK). You can use the '\b' trick, but be aware that some implementations won't '\b' past a '\n'.

Comment: Yup, tested that, it won't work for 2+ lines.

Comment: In addition, it won't work if stdout maps to a printer that has a spent *corrective fluid* cartridge. Bloody programmers and their '\b'! ;)

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: In fact, there are [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code](standards for terminals), and almost all modern terminals and emulators (other than ones used with IBM-style mainframes) support them.

Comment: @KeithThompson Fair enough. I see no mention of any of these standards in the C standard, so unless you're going somewhere with this discussion, I see no point in speculating on relevance.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: No, the C standard doesn't refer to all relevant standards that might be used by a C program. So what? The OP presumably isn't limited to writing 100% portable ISO C conforming code.

Comment: @KeithThompson Is there any evidence to suggest that the OP knows what is and isn't portable? If so, then there is no sensible rationale for this question or the discussion that's taken place in this comment space.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: The OP has clearly stated what he wants to do. If you don't think the OP understands the portability concerns, then you're free to explain them, or read about them in the answer I just posted. (Some forums discourage discussion of constructs not specified by the C standard; this is not one of those forums.)

Comment: I messed up the link in my previous comment. I meant to write "In fact, there are [standards for terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Regrading the title, aren't `linefeed` and `linebreak` interchangeable terms? How about `linebreak without linefeed character`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your terminal (or, much more likely, terminal emulator) supports VT100-style escape sequences, you can print specific code sequences to control the cursor position, clear some or all of the screen/window, etc.

For example, to move the cursor up 1 line:

```
printf("\x1b[A");
fflush(stdout);
```

To move the cursor up 2 lines, either do that twice or:

```
printf("\x1b[2A"});
fflush(stdout);
```

These are commonly referred to as [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code); the link is to a Wikipedia article that lists many of them. They were first implemented by the old DEC VT-100 terminal, which is emulated by most modern terminals and emulators.

And this:

```
printf("\x1b[J");
fflush(stdout);
```

will clear part of the screen, from the current cursor position to the bottom.

These sequences should be enough to do what you need. (They might not work in a Windows command window.)

More portably, if your system supports it, you can use `termcap` or `terminfo` to determine the proper command sequences for your current terminal (as determined by the `$TERM` environment variable).  The `tput` command lets you do this on the command line; `man tput` for more information. In practice, you're unlikely to find a system these days that supports termcap or terminfo with a terminal that's not VT100-compatible; printing raw escape sequences is strictly not portable, but probably good enough.

A suggestion: your program should probably have an option to inhibit any such control sequences; for example, if a user who wants to redirect the output to a file won't want to have those escape sequences in the file. Some programs use control sequences only if they can determine that stdout is a terminal, but an explicit option is also a good idea.

**UPDATE: **

Here's a program I threw together that demonstrates how to do this with the `terminfo`. It should work on just about any Unix-like system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *term = getenv("TERM");
    if (term == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "TERM environment variable is not set\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setterm(term);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        putp(tparm(clr_eos));
        printf("%d\n%d\n", i, i+1);
        sleep(1);
        putp(tparm(parm_up_cursor, 2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah that is great, this will definitely do. I've accepted yours as the answer since it addresses the question. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

To rewrite all (or part) of a line, you need to use the correct number of backspace characters.  Eg:

```
printf("some text");
printf("\b\b\b\bstuff");
```

Will output:

```
some stuff
```

This is fine for simple stuff; for something more complex you should use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) which uses ANSI-escape cleverness to manipulate the cursor around the screen.

Comment: `ncurses` assumes you want to take over the entire screen; as far as I know, it's not suitable for simple tasks like the OP wants to do without removing any text that's already been printed.